# Get the Category ID of a button in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm trying to get the value of the category ID on a click of a button but it's getting all the id's of my category when I click one of the buttons.

```
    const CategoryPage = ({ categories }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [click, setClick] = useState()

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const id = categories.map((category) => category._id)
    console.log(id)
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.scrollMenu}>
      {categories.map((category) => {
        return (
          <Button
            key={category._id}
            className={classes.button}
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)}
          >
            {category.name}
          </Button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `category.id` as the argument to the caller function.

```
const CategoryPage = ({ categories }) => {
const classes = useStyles()

const [click, setClick] = useState()

const handleClick = (categoryId) => { // clicked category id
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(categoryId)
}

return (
    <div className={classes.scrollMenu}>
       {categories.map((category) => {
          return (
             <Button
                key={category._id}
                className={classes.button}
                onClick={() => handleClick(category._id)} // this way
             >
             {category.name}
             </Button>
         )
       })}
   </div>
 )
}
```